# Javascript - How to call an internal class function from internal async function?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple js class that looks for a div and injects into it an img tag.

I need to call an internal function *stop()* if the user click on the div.

```
class PreDS {

constructor() {
    console.log("[PreDS] constr")
    this._el = document.querySelector(".imgOrari")
    if (this._el){
        this._el.innerHTML = "<img id='imgOrariImg'>";
        this._el.onclick =
            function(){
                console.log("[PreDS] click _el")
-->             stop("click")
            }
    }
    else console.error("class imgOrari not found")
}


stop(){
...
}
```

The problem is that the **onclick** handler defined like this, is not in the context of the object, so the function is *undefined*.

How can i recall the function?

Comment: Use `this.stop(...)` and have a look at [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ES6's fat arrow functions that transfer the context and don't create a new one like ES5's `function()`. Also you need to use `this.stop()` and not just `stop()`

```
this._el.onclick = () => {
                console.log("[PreDS] click _el")
                this.stop("click")
            }
```

Comment: Would `this._el.onclick = this.stop` work?

Comment: @Ben: Depends on whether `stop() {}` needs `this` to refer to the class instance or not. If yes, it won't work. But in that case you can bind the function: `this._el.onclick = this.stop.bind(this)`.

Comment: Solved: the fat arrow function solved the context problem. Thanks.